# Why Percentage unit in css doesnt work for fonts

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, percentage

From definition, CSS percentage unit has "size relative to parent size". However, in my case, it's not relative to parent size at all.

At least in case of font sizes. It's always the same. No matter if the div (so, it's parent) is 200px or 1000px.

Comment: A `font-size` specified in percent is relative _to the font-size_ of the parent element, not the actual height of the parent.

Comment: oh lols i see thanks

Answer (score -3):

just write `position: absolute;` in properties of that text. and then put the position. but it will be centered just in the div it is in.